# Writing an excel from a dictionary of tuples in python

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of tuples like below

```
mylist = {'file1': {'N': '96', 'P': '70', 'E': '109', 'T': '10'}, 'file2': {'N': '6', 'P': '90', 'E': '1309', 'T': '100'}', 'file3': {'N': '966', 'P': '370', 'E': '1409', 'T': '50'}}
```

If I extract it as a dataframe

```
df= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mylist, orient='index')
```

it works fine.
but when i try to write this df into an excel

```
df_cpu.to_excel (writer, "MY", index=True)
```

My excel does not have the file column.

Comment: Your dictionary has an error `'100'}'` though if you're just looking for the column to be named in the excel file as it's the index it won't have a label by default

To give it one you can do:

`df_cpu.to_excel (writer, "MY", index_label='file')`

Answer (score 1):

My Solution

First, install openpyxl

1.open cmd.exe
2.write the following command:

```
cd C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts
pip install openpyxl
```

Python code

```
mylist = {'file1': {'N': '96', 'P': '70', 'E': '109', 'T': '10'}, 'file2': {'N': '6', 'P': '90', 'E': '1309', 'T': '100'},'file3': {'N': '966', 'P': '370', 'E': '1409', 'T': '50'}}
df= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mylist, orient='index')
df.to_excel(r"C:\Users\Any\Desktop\output.xlsx",sheet_name='Sheet_name')
```

output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have openpyxl installed (can be installed with `pip install openpyxl`), the following should work.

```
mylist = {
    "file1": {"N": "96", "P": "70", "E": "109", "T": "10"},
    "file2": {"N": "6", "P": "90", "E": "1309", "T": "100"},
    "file3": {"N": "966", "P": "370", "E": "1409", "T": "50"},
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mylist, orient="index")
output = "OUTPUT.xlsx"
sheet_name = "MY"
df.to_excel(output, sheet_name, index=True)
```

The resulting excel file doesn't have a header for the "file" column.  If you wanted to add one, you could instead do

```
df.to_excel(output, sheet_name, index=True, index_label="file") # Replace "file" with whatever header you prefer)
```

Alternatively, because the resulting file is quite simple, you could choose to simply use `df.to_csv` instead

`df.to_csv(output)`

Comment: Thanks much. Adding the index_label works perfectly.
df_cpu.to_excel (writer, "MY", index=True, index_label="filename")